# No me reconoce mi public class en aspx

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de realizar un `using VPCBC_1.App_Code.VPCRequest` para localizar mi clase ubicada en mi ruta `App_Code`
tal y como lo señalo en mi imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que no me reconoce nada.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo `VPCRequest`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AquÍ dejo mis using de donde intento jalar el `VPCRequest`

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using VPCBC_1.App_Code.VPCRequest
```

Comment: En lugar de pegar imágenes de tu código, coloca el código directamente en tu pregunta para que sea más legible

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Por lo que veo en la imagen el nombre completo de la clase es _TNS.VPCRequest (y no como intentas colocar VPCBC_1.App_Code.VPCRequest)

Answer (score 2):

Tu `using` está mal, tu clase `VPCRequest` está en el namespace `_TNS`.

Cámbialo por `using _TNS;`

Por otro lado y no tiene que ver con la solución: Tienes demasiado `using` que están de más. Todos aquellos que se ven como desactivados deberían ser eliminados sin ningún problema.

Comment: use el using _TNS;
pero me marca que esta desactivada